# How to count number of times a date has been used?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I count how many times a date is in a table column using php and mysql?

I am trying to figure out a way to limit the amount of dates can be used for rows

for example:

```
1   1   0000-00-00  2   yes     2013-10-06 20:07:17 2013-10-06 20:07:17
2   1   0000-00-00  4   yes 1   2013-10-06 20:19:31 2013-10-06 20:19:31
3   1   2013-10-15  2   yes 1   2013-10-06 20:22:14 2013-10-06 20:22:14
4   1   2013-10-30  3   yes 1   2013-10-06 21:07:28 2013-10-06 21:07:28
```

I want to return an error if 2013-10-30 has been used 5 times.

I am using Laravel 4 and saving the data using a model

```
    if (<<<<code goes here???>>>>>){
        return Redirect::to('')->withErrors($full)->withInput();
    }

    $schedule->userID = $user->id;
    $schedule->date = $dateFormat;
    $schedule->block = $input['timeslot'];
    $schedule->status = "1";

    $schedule->save();
```

Comment: `code goes here` --- `<<<<payment for the job goes here>>>>>`

Comment: Maybe if you concentrated on helping rather than passive aggressive remarks we could all work together here.

Comment: I could be concentrating on help if you asked something more particular. Do you know how to perform sql queries in laravel? Do you know how to select what you need in pure sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do something like this:

`Schedule::where('timeslot', '=', $date)->count()` in addition, if that piece of code is used here and there you could create it as a [query scope](http://ifonlyiknewthat.com/laravel/laravel-4-orm-query-scope/) so you can call it in fashion like Schedule::countForTimeslot($date) anywhere or as a part of more complex query on top of the model.

Comment: Funny I actually changed it to your suggestion shortly after looking at Casey's last night. His code was counting every row not the actual dates.. I will def look at that Query Scope that looks very useful thanks bud!

Answer (score 1):

The sql statement you want it is

```
SELECT COUNT (id) FROM table WHERE DATE(date_field) = :date
```

don't use rowCount that should be used to count row affected (like in a delete or update)

Comment: Either is correct. If assuming that id is indexed and doesn't allow nulls there shouldn't be a performance difference. Oops, missed the parens.

Comment: I was thinking about the COUNT() function. But was worried about performance. Is their a way to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: What do you mean achieve in php?

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do this in PHP using Laravel 4 model that was already being called. However, I found this to be an acceptable resolution. $results = DB::table('bk_schedule')->count();

Comment: No problem. Laravel does have a way to issue a count using it's framework using DB::raw in the ->select. Something to put in your bag for the future.